# order number auto create based on previous number

Tags: php

What I want to do is create an automatic order number. So like this date-number of order
So the first order of today would be
`20190719-01`
second-order of today would be
`20190719-02`
etc.

Then tomorrow it needs to be like `20190720-01 20190720-02` etc and so on.

How can I achieve this? preferably in PHP

Comment: The numbering is usually based on an AUTO INCREMENT field in a database.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I understand but how can I reset it back to -01 when a new date arrives

Comment: I have not tried anything since I dont really now what I need to do. I can easily just do date and then + a number but I need that when a new date arrives that it reset that number

Answer (score 0):

`str_pad()` is your friend here.

```
$range = range(1,10);
$period = new DatePeriod(
     new DateTime('2019-07-17'),
     new DateInterval('P1D'),
     new DateTime('2019-07-20')
);

foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
    foreach($range as $inc){
      $seq = str_pad($inc,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);    
      $order_number = $value->format('Ymd').'-'.$seq;
      echo $order_number.PHP_EOL;    
    } 
    echo PHP_EOL."===========".PHP_EOL;
}
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/R5POt

Comment: this does it all in one time. I need it so when I create a new order it remembers the previous order number

Answer (score 0):

Normally order numbers would be sequential, and can therefore easily be derived from the AUTO INCREMENT field. In your case this is not so easy.

You could start by getting the highest AUTO INCREMENT field from the database for all orders before today:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM orders WHERE DATE(orderDate) < CURDATE();
```

Let us call this id `$offsetId`. If no orders exist yet it should be zero.

Then first insert the order information into the database, so you can get the `id` of that order. You can do this either with `$con->insert_id` in MySQLi or [lastInsertId()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) in PDO. let's call this the `$orderId`.

The reason, to use a database in this way, is to prevent that two orders ever get the same order number.

Now you can compute the order number for today:

```
$orderNumber = date("Ymd") . "-" . sprintf('%02d', $orderId - $offsetId);
```

And you can store this in the database, with the order.

You should probably anticipate more than 99 orders a day...